# Creating reactive wrapper around networking

Tags: swift, alamofire, reactive-programming, rx-swift, reactivex

While creating reactive extensions for my networking layer I've noticed some *patterns* which I'd like to extract just to simplyfy my logic for future implementations... So what I have right now is a couple of methods similiar to this one:

```
static func create(params: [ String: AnyObject ]) -> Observable<Type> {
    return Observable<Type>.create { observer -> Disposable in
        let request = Alamofire.request(TypeAPI.Create(params: params).responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .Success(let value):
                guard response.response?.statusCode != 409 else {
                    observer.onError(RequestError.TypeAlreadyExists)
                    return
                }

                guard let dict = value as? [ String: AnyObject ] else {
                    observer.onError(RequestError.ParsingError)
                    return
                }

                guard let parsedType: Type = try? Unbox(dict) else {
                    observer.onError(RequestError.MappingError)
                    return
                }

                observer.onNext(parsedType)
            case .Failure(let error):
                observer.onError(RequestError.convert(error))
            }
        }

        return AnonymousDisposable {
            request.cancel()
        }
    }
}
```

And for example `AnonymousDisposable` thing is always repeating.
I've looked at `RxAlamofire` implementation and their [`rx_request` method](https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxAlamofire/blob/develop/RxAlamofire/Source/RxAlamofire.swift#L338) is basically following pretty familiar pattern, but I'm a bit stuck when I try to actually use `RxAlamofire` with my current wrapper. So far I've ended with something like:

```
static func rx_create(params: [ String: AnyObject ]) -> Observable<Type> {
    let manager: Manager = Manager.sharedInstance
    manager.rx_request { manager -> Request in
        return Alamofire.request(TypeAPI.Create(params: params))
    }
}
```

But `rx_request` returns `Observable<Request>` and I need `Observable<Type>`. If I go and add `.flatMap` than I'll finish with `AnonymousDisposable` again...

Any suggestions what's the right approach? Am I somewhere near at least? Or am I going completely wrong direction?

Answer (score 0):

Got something... At least I guess I got something. It works and for now I'm happy with this solution, so let's jump to the conclusion.

Path with `.flatMap` was correct one, but to avoid additional `Observable.create` I had to go deeper into `RxAlamofire` and benefit from this nice `rx_responseJSON` method

But then I'v realized that I can go even further and extract this process, so I've finished with generic method common for all my request wrapper classes, which looks like this:

```
static func rx_request<T>(requestConvertible: URLRequestConvertible, completion: (Request) -> Observable<T> ) -> Observable<T> {
    let manager: Manager = Manager.sharedInstance
    return manager
        .rx_request { manager -> Request in
            return Alamofire.request(requestConvertible)
        }
        .flatMap { request -> Observable<T> in
            return completion(request)
        }
        .shareReplay(1)
}
```

Now I'm able to use this method like here:

```
static func rx_create(options: String) -> Observable<Type> {
    return rx_request(TypesAPI.Create(options: options)) { request -> Observable<Type> in
        request
            .validate()
            .rx_responseJSON()
            .flatMap{ (request, json) -> Observable<Type> in
                guard
                    let dict = json as? [ String: AnyObject ],
                    let parsedType: Type = try? Unbox(dict) else {
                        return Observable.error(RequestError.ParsingError)
                }

                return Observable.just(parsedType)
            }
    }
}
```

Which in my opinion looks a bit cleaner ☺️